# Outlook lost all contacts created in some timeframe

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

One of my colleague has been creating a lot of contact for last two days. She is in the process of doing that thing and she said she created almost 100 contact yesterdsy and she says that she is not able to see any of the contacts that she created yesterday.

Now, I checked her PST and it is getting updated everyday. She has been able to send and recieve eMails back and forth. That tells me that her PST has not lost the data. Then why would she not see any of the contact that she created yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

Has she lost anything else, like email or tasks or anything?  Is it possible she created them in a folder other than the [default] contacts folder (look through her folder list).  I would also ask her *how* she created the contacts and make sure she wasn't using the windows address book, which is still available in some versions of Outlook.